# Boto3 AWS Codecommit Delete Folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

Issue is that you can create and update multiple files, with something like `.create_commit`. However, you can't do the reverse, you can delete files **1 by 1**, using the function mentioned in the docs.

For the client I use `boto3` and `boto3.client('codecommit')`

Reference - [boto3 docs - delete file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.46/reference/services/codecommit.html#CodeCommit.Client.delete_file)

**Question:**
How to delete folders with **boto3** and **aws** **codecommit**?

Only the following 4 methods are available:

- `delete_branch()`
- `delete_comment_content()`
- `delete_file()`
- `delete_repository()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS codecommit doesn't allow deleting **directories** (folders). This implementation works, instead of deleting the whole directory at once, you find all the files and then delete them.

Basic overview.

1. **Get FileNames inside Folder** using `.get_folder()` *note that his gives a lot more info**
2. **Clean `.get_folder`** - *clean output not just the filepaths, we only require filepaths*
3. **Commit (delete)**

Where `REPOSITORY_NAME` is the **name of your repository** and `folderPath` is the name of the **folder that you want to delete**.

```
files = codecommit_client.get_folder(repositoryName=REPOSITORY_NAME, folderPath=PATH)
```

Now we use that information, to create a commit with deleted files, we had to do some manipulation since the deleteFiles param takes only filepaths and the information that we got with `.get_folder` contains a lot more than just filepaths. Please replace `branchName` if you need *(currently main)*

```
codecommit_client.create_commit(
            repositoryName=REPOSITORY_NAME,
            branchName='main',
            parentCommitId=files['commitId'],
            commitMessage=f"DELETED Files",
            deleteFiles=[{'filePath':x['absolutePath']} for x in files['files']],
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a folder, set `keepEmptyFolders=False` when invoking [delete_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.46/reference/services/codecommit.html#CodeCommit.Client.delete_file) on the last file in that folder. I'm not aware of a single API function that will delete an entire folder and all of its contents.

Note: by default, empty folders will be deleted when calling [delete_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.46/reference/services/codecommit.html#CodeCommit.Client.delete_file).

Comment: That's not the issue, my problem isn't with empty directories, I am unable to delete any kind of directory only one file.

Comment: Your question was "how to delete folders?" You can't, not directly afaik. You delete the files from the folder and then the folder itself will be deleted when the folder becomes empty (unless you explicitly indicated `keepEmptyFolders=True` on the last call to `delete_file()`. Perhaps you could clarify what you mean by "I am unable to delete any kind of directory only one file." Are you asking "how do I delete a folder and all of its contents in one call?" I don't see a way to do that.

Comment: exactly but you haven't provided me with a solution, I appreciate the input tho, I have posted a solution, list all files within and then delete them.